# Why does DNS Spoofing not working on HTTP ,HTTPS Sites? [in my case]

Tags: network, firewalls, man-in-the-middle, dns-spoofing

I am trying to perform a DNS spoofing attack, but the confusing thing is that when I'm  performing the attack on **HTTP** sites, nothing happens.

But when I perform it on **HTTPS** sites, when I reach the target site, I get the message: "Your Connection is not Private"!

My commands on Kali Linux by using Ettercap was

`echo > 1 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

and then I edited the `etter.conf` and deleted both # under the *iptables* section and put my website target in `etter.dns` under the *microsoft sucks* like this:

`*.example.com A my ip`

and the same last one but start with

`www.example.com  A  my ip`

next command was `service apache2 start`

and finally `ettercap -T -q -i wlan0 -M arp:remote -P dns_spoof /ROUTER IP/ /TARGET IP/`

So after these commands i definitely expect to display my Apache instead of "example.com", but as i said the result was no effect on http sites, and "Your Connection is not Private" message on https.

My main question is why doesn't this attack work for both of http, https,
Do you think it's because the router settings or is there something missing?

Comment: if you look at the packet traces, you should be able to see what's going on. You'll be able to see if ettercap is working and sending the correct info to the correct target

Comment: I think It's a good idea to tracking the data but do you have any application you can recommend me with!

Comment: wireshark is the standard if you want a GUI or `tcpdump` for commandline

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend that before you go further in learning ettercap that you first learn how to capture and interpret packets

Answer (score 1):

Try only with the target ip specified:                                        `ettercap -i wlan0 -T -M arp -P dns_spoof /TARGET IP///`

Comment: I tried `ettercap -i wlan0 -T -M arp -P dns_spoof /TARGET IP///` but it's did not changed any thing unfortunately.

Comment: sounds like your server is not up(running) or the other fake site might be incorrectly configured. Check the file /etc/ettercap/etter.dns. It should contain * A TARGET IP where denotes All address records.

Comment: I believe i make every step right and correct, i'm even watched some youtube videos and i copied each step, but all ways mine don't work.
so It's definitely a Hard situation to tell what's the problem.

Comment: I am assuming that you have used elevated privilege with the command. i.e. sudo ettercap -i wlan0 -T -M arp -P dns_spoof /TARGET IP///.